# how to modify an array from another class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object

Im making to do list-app which consist of 2 View Controllers 
one with table view hold an array and display it and second one with a textField, a button function to append the text field's text to the array
to display the new appended string it in the first view controller
heres my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var exmpArray = ["DDDD","rrr","TTT"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
@IBAction func addBtnBar(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMe", sender: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return exmpArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = exmpArray[indexPath.row]  
    return cell!
}}
```

**and the second one is:**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

var realAry:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

let myObj = ViewController()

@IBAction func addBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    myObj.exmpArray.append(myTextField.text!)
    print(myObj.exmpArray)        

}
```

after appending the new words it doesn't display in the first controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both arrays are different you are just copying first VC array to 2nd VC array. Array is value type in swift. Instead of creating 2 arrays make 1st VC array as static.

```
static var exmpArray = ["DDDD","rrr","TTT"]
```

Now you can use & update this in all VC by calling like below

`FirstVC.exmpArray`

Comment: thanks that worked --- i can see the new values when i print it in the console but now i only need to use tableView.reloadData() to show it in the table ... can you please advice where i can implement this function in my class ?

Comment: Who downvoted this? Its a reasonable answer, and provides useful information.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is this line:

```
let myObj = ViewController()
```

That creates a new instance of ViewController that has nothing to do with the view controller that called you. Get rid of that line. It's wrong.

You need to set up a delegate property in `SecondViewController` that points back to `ViewController`, define a protocol for that delegate to conform to, and use that protocol so that `SecondViewController` can notify it's delegate when the array changes.

In `ViewController`, add a prepareForSegue() function that takes the destination view controller, casts it to type `SecondViewController`, and sets `SecondViewController`'s delegate to self.