# Swift: How Can I update arrray.count in other VC after append? For Loop for UIAlert Actions

Tags: ios, swift

Rookie here trying to make a an expense tracker app for exercise. I uploaded the project to GitHub. I can't figure out how to update the data array count in TabBarViewController vc where I have a for loop to create action buttons on alert controller.

I made an x int object on home view controller to update it to new data.count in add category() and I also tried tableview numberofsections.

How can I change alert2 (alert controller) to include all categories even after user appended something to the data array?

https://github.com/ipanzerkampfwagen/xsavvytest/tree/main/XSavvy

This is button func which includes for loop, alert and actions in tabbar vc.

```
@objc func buttonClicked() {
   
 
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Spent Money?", message: "Add New Item", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Category", message: "Choose Category", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let alert3 = UIAlertController(title: "Cost", message: "Type Cost/Price", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
    
        

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in
                
                    
                 
                
                    
                for i in 0..<self.home.x {
    
     
                        alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: self.home.data[i].categoryArray, style: .default, handler: { (action2) in
                            
                            

                        
                            alert3.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cost", style: .default, handler: { (action3) in
                                
                                
                                if let cost = Double(self.textFieldCost.text!) {
                                    self.home.data[i].cost.append(cost)
                                } else {
                                    self.home.data[i].cost.append(0.00)
                                }
                         
                                
                             
                            }))
                            
                      
                            self.home.data[i].log.append(self.textField.text!)
                            
                        
                            
                            self.present(alert3, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        }) )
            
                        

                    }

                    
                

                alert3.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
                    alertTextField.placeholder = "Price of the Item/Service"
                    self.textFieldCost = alertTextField
                }
                
                
                alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
                    }))
                
                self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        }
    
                alert.addAction(action)
            
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
                }))
            
         
           
            alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
                alertTextField.placeholder = "Add Item"
                self.textField = alertTextField
            }
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            

    }
```

In home vc I have this func triggered by sliding the tableview cell. This is where the appending happens.

```
    var data: [CategoryLogPass] = [CategoryLogPass(categoryArray: "Grocery", log: ["Chocolate Bar", "Bread"], cost: [3, 1]),
            CategoryLogPass(categoryArray: "Coffee", log: ["Latte", "Filter Coffee"], cost: [2, 1]),
            CategoryLogPass(categoryArray: "Rent", log: ["Home", "Office"], cost: [2, 1]),
            CategoryLogPass(categoryArray: "Clothing", log: ["Shirt", "Pants"], cost: [2, 1])
]
```

func addCategory() {

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add item", style: .default) { (action) in
        // what will happen once the user clicks the add item button on our UI alert
        
        self.data.append(CategoryLogPass(categoryArray: self.textField1.text!, log: [""], cost: [0]))

  

        
        
   //modify this to change the indextPath.row cell.
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.x = self.tableView.numberOfSections
        
        
    }
    
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Add Category"
        self.textField1 = alertTextField
        
    }
    
    alert.addAction(action)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
        
    }))
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend uploading codes directly here rather than posting a link.

Comment: I made the data array static and it worked. Thanks to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119600/how-to-modify-an-array-from-another-class